# How can I delay obs 1 until obs 2 has not emitted for x seconds?

Tags: rxjs, observable, delay, debouncing

[image]I have one obs whose emission should wait until a different obs has stopped firing for a certain period of time, then emit latest.

```js
const {Subject, interval} = rxjs;
const {take} = rxjs.operators;

const subject = new Subject(0)

interval(1000)
  .pipe(take(2))
  // detect that subject has recently fired and delay until
  // 1000 after most recent subject emission, then take only latest
  .subscribe(r => console.log(r))

subject.subscribe(r => console.log('subject emission'))

setTimeout(() => {
  subject.next(1);
}, 500)

setTimeout(() => {
  subject.next(2);
}, 1200)
```

Actual results:

```
subject emission
0
subject emission
1
```

Desired results

```
subject emission
subject emission
// one second to be sure no immediate emissions happening
1
```

Edit as per @benshabatnoam's comment. I used interval because it was a quick tool to reach for and that was a mistake. In my actual case it is not predictable. It should be represented by an obs that could fire at any time. Thus the actual desired results should be something like:

```
// gold obs fires but notices subject is emitting
subject emission
subject emission
// one second to be sure no immediate emissions happening
1
// gold obs fires a few seconds later and sees there are no subject emissions
2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `combineLatest`, `debounceTime` and `map`:

```js
const main$ = new Subject(0);

main$.subscribe(() => console.log('subject emission'))


// aux$ could be any observable
const aux$ = interval(1000).pipe(
  take(2)
)


setTimeout(() => main$.next(1), 500);
setTimeout(() => main$.next(2), 1200);

combineLatest(main$, aux$).pipe(
  map(([main, _aux]) => main),
  debounceTime(1000), // define your own delay time here
).subscribe(result => console.log(result))
```

result is as expected.

**edit** given the new comment, `withLatestFrom` is probably the operator you're looking for:

```
aux$.pipe(
    withLatestFrom(main$),
    map(([_aux, main]) => main),
    debounceTime(1000),
)
```

Comment: Thanks. This gets pretty close. What if we add a main$.next(3), 5000? The problem with this solution is that main$ can trigger an emission for aux$ which is not desired. An event from aux$ should be the only thing that can lead to invocation of the fn provided to subscribe.

Comment: See edit, instead of combineLatest you can use withLatestFrom to use only one obs as the signal for emission

Comment: `withLatestFrom` is not a viable solution because I still care primarily about the emissions of `main$` independent of `aux$`. See problem [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-uqt8h5)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: If I understand you correctly this pipe will do the job:

```
this.obs1.pipe(
  debounceTime(1000),
  switchMap(() => this.obs2)
)
```

The logic in this pipe is to wait a sec when `obs` is firing (using the [debounceTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html) operator) and then switch it to listen to the second observable (using the [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) operator).

Here are demos for your question:

[Reproducing the problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-console-reproduce)

[Fixing the problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-console-reproduce-fix) (**UPDATED**)

cheers

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was trying to get at (was trying to do it with delay). However, it doesn't work as desired. If the subject continues to fire, the interval is not delayed. Interval (or any obs) needs to wait until subject has not emitted for 1 second [Still a problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-console-reproduce-fix-bq7zzd)

Comment: I don't understand the problem or what is the desired result in case that subject is continuing to fire. in my solution the interval in not continuing to fire. isn't that what you're looking for? update your answer in the *desired result* section to demonstrate what do you expect to get after subject is continuing to fire

Comment: @dras see my comment above

Comment: I apologize. I mixed up what I meant to say. I have updated the question. Basically in [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-console-reproduce-fix-zfa1a7) how can I get 'emit obs 2' do happen. It's like I need to conditionally debounce.